# useState not setting after initial setting

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-google-maps

I have a functional component that is using `useState` and uses the `@react-google-maps/api` component.  I have a map that uses an onLoad function to initalize a custom control on the map (with a click event).  I then set state within this click event.  It works the first time, but every time after that doesn't toggle the value.

Function component:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';

export default function MyMap(props) {
    const [radiusDrawMode, setRadiusDrawMode] = React.useState(false);

    const toggleRadiusDrawMode = useCallback((map) => {        
        map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: (!radiusDrawMode) ? 'crosshair' : 'grab' });

        setRadiusDrawMode(!radiusDrawMode);
    }, [setRadiusDrawMode, radiusDrawMode]); // Tried different dependencies.. nothing worked

    const mapInit = useCallback((map) => {
        var radiusDiv = document.createElement('div');
        radiusDiv.index = 1;

        var radiusButton = document.createElement('div');
        radiusDiv.appendChild(radiusButton);

        var radiusText = document.createElement('div');
        radiusText.innerHTML = 'Radius';
        radiusButton.appendChild(radiusText);

        radiusButton.addEventListener('click', () => toggleRadiusDrawMode(map));

        map.controls[window.google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(radiusDiv);
    }, [toggleRadiusDrawMode, radiusDrawMode, setRadiusDrawMode]); // Tried different dependencies.. nothing worked

    return (
        <LoadScript id="script-loader" googleMapsApiKey="GOOGLE_API_KEY">
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMap id='google-map'
                    onLoad={(map) => mapInit(map)}>
                </GoogleMap>
            </div>
        </LoadScript>
    );
}
```

The first time the user presses the button on the map, it setss the `radiusDrawMode` to `true` and sets the correct cursor for the map (crosshair).  Every click of the button after does not update `radiusDrawMode` and it stays in the `true` state.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's a cache issue with `useCallback`. Try removing the `useCallback`s to test without that optimization. If it works, you'll know for sure, and then you can double check what should be memoized and what maybe should not be.

I'd start by removing the one from `toggleRadiusDrawMode`:

```
const toggleRadiusDrawMode = map => {        
  map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: (!radiusDrawMode) ? 'crosshair' : 'grab' });

  setRadiusDrawMode(!radiusDrawMode);
};
```

Also, can you access the state of the `map` options (the ones that you're setting with `map.setOptions`)? If so, it might be worth using the actual state of the map's option rather than creating your own internal state to track the same thing. Something like (I'm not positive that it would be `map.options`):

```
const toggleRadiusDrawMode = map => {
  const { draggableCursor } = map.options;
  map.setOptions({
    draggableCursor: draggableCursor === 'grab' ? 'crosshair' : 'grab'
  });
};
```

Also, I doubt this is the issue, but it looks like you're missing a closing bracket on the `<GoogleMap>` element? (Also, you might not need to create the intermediary function between `onLoad` and `mapInit`, and can probably pass `mapInit` directly to the `onLoad`.)

```
<GoogleMap id='google-map'
  onLoad={mapInit}>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  But none of the above worked.  I'm pretty sure this has something to with scope of the eventListener, but not sure quite what.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up using to solve this problem.

I basically had to switch out using a `useState(false)` for `setRef(false)`.  Then set up a useEffect to listen to changes on the ref, and in the actual `toggleRadiusDraw` I set the reference value which fires the `useEffect` to set the actual ref value.

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';

export default function MyMap(props) {
    const radiusDrawMode = useRef(false);

    let currentRadiusDrawMode = radiusDrawMode.current;

    useEffect(() => {
        radiusDrawMode.current = !radiusDrawMode;
    });

    const toggleRadiusDrawMode = (map) => {  
        map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: (!currentRadiusDrawMode) ? 'crosshair' : 'grab' });

        currentRadiusDrawMode = !currentRadiusDrawMode;
    };

    const mapInit = (map) => {
        var radiusDiv = document.createElement('div');
        radiusDiv.index = 1;

        var radiusButton = document.createElement('div');
        radiusDiv.appendChild(radiusButton);

        var radiusText = document.createElement('div');
        radiusText.innerHTML = 'Radius';
        radiusButton.appendChild(radiusText);

        radiusButton.addEventListener('click', () => toggleRadiusDrawMode(map));

        map.controls[window.google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(radiusDiv);
    });

    return (
        <LoadScript id="script-loader" googleMapsApiKey="GOOGLE_API_KEY">
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMap id='google-map'
                    onLoad={(map) => mapInit(map)}>
                </GoogleMap>
            </div>
        </LoadScript>
    );
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way to handle this, but hope it helps someone else in the future.